# Module error while installing add-ons of ckediter 5 of angular

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

I'm working on adding a library to ckediter 5, but when I add the .js file to the component, an error occurs as shown. If I remove the .js file, everything works fine. Please support me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: please we need more information show us your code without sensitives informations

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.